# Gradle build of java application gives java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle, keytool

## Issue

When building a java application with gradle:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.pom'.
            > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.746 secs
```

## The Fix

- Downloading a JDK 8 from Oracle, and copying the cacerts file over mine works.
- I'm not sure if it's specific to the JDK from Oracle, if it's JDK 8, or if it would work with the opensdk's...  but the issue *is* the cacerts file.
- The cacerts file is preloaded with the jdk install, ex: `~/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
- My cacerts file is located in /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts.

^^ Kinda a hacky fix, but it works.

I really hope someone finds this helpful.  I ran into this issue on a day where I had to get a lot done and this was a serious headache.

Answer (score 1):

## The Fix

- Downloading a JDK 8 from Oracle, and copying the cacerts file over mine works.
- I'm not sure if it's specific to the JDK from Oracle, if it's JDK 8, or if it would work with the opensdk's... but the issue is the cacerts file.
- The cacerts file is preloaded with the jdk install, ex: ~/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/security/cacerts
- My cacerts file is located in /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts.

^^ Kinda a hacky fix, but it works.

I really hope someone finds this helpful. I ran into this issue on a day where I had to get a lot done and this was a serious headache.